# Excluding Types in Haskell

Tags: haskell

How would I use pattern matching in order to exclude certain types of inputs? For instance given the following:

```
f list k =
    if null list
    then []
    else head list + k : f (tail list) k
```

How can I use pattern matching to make f s/t it only allows Int and Integer but not Double or Float?

Comment: You should not be trying to pattern match on types.  If you want to make a function like `map (+k)` operate only over a particular set of types then give it a suitable type constraint.

Comment: Good point! thanks

Answer (score 3):

`f`/`mapAdd` implements a `map`. `map` is

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map _ []       = []
map f (x : xs) = f x : map f xs
```

and can be used to formulate `mapAdd`:

```
Prelude> mapAdd n  =  map (+ n)
Prelude> mapAdd 3 [1,2,3,4]
[4,5,6,7]
```

GHCi's `:type` command tells you the automatically inferred type signature of `mapAdd`:

```
Prelude> :type mapAdd
mapAdd :: Num b => b -> [b] -> [b]
```

Here, `mapAdd`'s `b`s are constrained to the general numerical *type class* `Num`. You can explicitly constrain to the type class [`Integral`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral), which (basically) exclusively contains the data types `Int`, and `Integer`. `Integral` is a *subclass* of `Num`.

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| mapAdd :: Integral a => a -> [a] -> [a]
Prelude| mapAdd n  =  map (+ n)
Prelude| :}
Prelude> :t mapAdd
mapAdd :: Integral a => a -> [a] -> [a]
```

---

`mapAdd n  =  map (+ n)` is *pointfree* for `mapAdd n lst = map (+ n) lst`.

Comment: `Integral` includes `Integer`, `Natural`, `Int`, `Int8`, `Int16`, `Int32`, `Int64`, `Word`, `Word8`, `Word16`, `Word32`, and `Word64`.

Comment: @dfeuer Absolutely, there's a complete list of the `Integral` data types at the link. But I believe `Integral` is the floating-exclusive constrain OP was looking for. I don't think a new type class definition makes sense in this context.

Comment: I agree with your general approach; I just disagree with the details, especially since we have `Natural` now.

Answer (score 3):

As suchtgott explained, you should not actually try to limit your function to exactly `Int` and `Integer`; you probably want to use an `Integral` constraint.

Suppose, for fun, that you really did want to limit it just like that. The way to do this in Haskell 98 is a bit weird (jump down to the break to see how this is done in GHC Haskell:

```
class Integral a => IntOrInteger a where
  intOrInteger :: Either (f a -> f Int) (f a -> f Integer)
instance IntOrInteger Int where
  intOrInteger = Left id
instance IntOrInteger Integer where
  intOrInteger = Right id
```

How do you use such a thing? Well, to start off with

```
intOrIntegerSimple :: IntOrInteger a => Either (a -> Int) (a -> Integer)
intOrIntegerSimple = case intOrInteger of
  Left f -> Left (runIdentity . f . Identity)
  Right f -> Right (runIdentity . f . Identity)
```

But how do you flip it around, and turn an `Int` or `Integer` back to an instance of `IntOrInteger`?

```
newtype Switch f a i = Switch {runSwitch :: f i -> f a}

intOrInteger' :: IntOrInteger a => Either (f Int -> f a) (f Integer -> f a)
intOrInteger' = case intOrInteger of
                  Left f -> Left (runSwitch (f (Switch id)))
                  Right f -> Right (runSwitch (f (Switch id)))

intOrIntegerSimple' :: IntOrInteger a => Either (Int -> a) (Integer -> a)
intOrIntegerSimple' = case intOrInteger' of
  Left f -> Left (runIdentity . f . Identity)
  Right f -> Right (runIdentity . f . Identity)
```

When you don't really care whether you have an `Int` or an `Integer`, but want to be sure you really have one of them, you have to watch out for invalid instances. What might an invalid instance look like? This is one option:

```
instance IntOrInteger Word where
  intOrInteger = Left (const undefined)
```

To just test that the instance is valid, you can use this (importing `Data.Proxy`):

```
ensureIntOrInteger :: IntOrInteger a => Proxy a -> ()
ensureIntOrInteger p = case intOrInteger of
  Left f -> f p `seq` ()
  Right f -> f p `seq` ()
```

The result of `ensureIntOrInteger` will be defined if and only if the type `a` is actually an `Int` or an `Integer`.

---

Nice; it works. But in practice it's pretty nasty to use. You can do much better with a few GHC extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators, ConstraintKinds,
      UndecidableInstances, UndecidableSuperClasses, DataKinds #-}

-- In 8.0 and later, Constraint is also available from Data.Kind
import GHC.Exts (Constraint)
import Data.Type.Equality ((:~:)(..))
import GHC.TypeLits (TypeError, ErrorMessage (..))

type family IntOrIntegerC a :: Constraint where
  IntOrIntegerC Int = ()
  IntOrIntegerC Integer = ()
  IntOrIntegerC t = TypeError ('ShowType t :<>:
                               'Text " is not an Int or an Integer.")

class (Integral a, IntOrIntegerC a) => IntOrInteger a where
  intOrInteger :: Either (a :~: Int) (a :~: Integer)
instance IntOrInteger Int where
  intOrInteger = Left Refl
instance IntOrInteger Integer where
  intOrInteger = Right Refl
```

With this formulation, the `IntOrIntegerC` constraint family blocks out any invalid types without your needing to do *anything*, giving a useful error message if someone tries to write a bogus instance. And if you actually do need to use the equality evidence, it's simply a matter of pattern matching on `intOrInteger` or using the various handy functions in `Data.Type.Equality`.

---

A point of style: using `head` and `tail` is generally discouraged in Haskell. We prefer to pattern match instead. Your function could be written

```
f [] _ = []
f (x : xs) k = x + k : f xs k
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dumb type class with instances only for `Int` and `Integer` and then use a type constraint:

```
class (Num a) => IntOrInteger a
instance IntOrInteger Int
instance IntOrInteger Integer

f :: (IntOrInteger a) => [a] -> a -> [a]
f list k =
    if null list
    then []
    else head list + k : f (tail list) k
```

Then if you use `f` with `Int`, it will compile:

```
> f [1,2,3] 1
[2,3,4]
```

But it will not compile with `Double`:

```
> f [1,2,3] (1::Double)

<interactive>:19:1: error:
    * No instance for (IntOrInteger Double) arising from a use of `f'
    * In the expression: f [1, 2, 3] (1 :: Double)
      In an equation for `it': it = f [1, 2, 3] (1 :: Double)
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that, if the OP doesn't literally need it to accept `Int` and `Integer` *and nothing else*, plain old `Integral` will likely be enough.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to constrain types, the most direct is just with type families.

```
type family Elem x xs :: Constraint where
    Elem x (x ': xs) = ()
    Elem x (y ': xs) = Elem x xs
    Elem x '[] = TypeError ('ShowType x :<>: 'Text " is not a permitted type.")

type a ~~ b = Elem a b

function :: (a ~~ [Int, Integer], Num a) => [a] -> [a]
```

This allows you to white list a set of types. You won't know which one in particular you have though, that's more complicated.

However, you said you wanted to *exclude* certain types, so perhaps you want a black list. We simply flip the first and last case:

```
type family NotElem x xs :: Constraint where
    NotElem x (x ': xs) = TypeError ('ShowType x :<>: 'Text " is a forbidden type.")
    NotElem x (y ': xs) = NotElem x xs
    NotElem x '[] = ()

type a !~~ b = NotElem a b

function :: (a !~~ [Double, Float], Num a) => [a] -> [a]
```

`function` will now accept any `Num` type that is *not* a Double or Float.

However, there's no reason to actually do any of this for your example function. You lose nothing at all by allowing it to work on the full range of `Num` types. In fact, these hijinks will at the least cost you a tiny smidgen more time on type checking, or if you go further and do reflection based things, possibly run time overhead as well.